# .htaccess redirect to https using different variables

Tags: .htaccess, http, variables, redirect, https

I'd like to force http to https redirect via htaccess.

The problem is that my development server uses %{HTTPS} variable while my production server uses %{ENV:HTTPS} variable.

Is there some way how to determine which variable should i use now? In pseudocode I want to achieve something like this:

```
if (is_defined %{HTTPS}) {
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
}
else if (is_defined %{ENV:HTTPS}) {
    RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !^.*on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod-rewite **[OR]** flag to check both variables at the same time.

```
RewriteEngine on

#if 1 of these 2 conditions is met
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
#redirect the url
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

or you can simply check the %{REQUEST_SCHEME} variable. This  works on apache versions 2.4+

```
RewriteCond %{REQUERT_SCHEME} http$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```